# SonarQube shows issues when resolved

Tags: sonarqube

After making the recommened changes, simple ones i.e System.out to System.err, Sonar still shows the incident as shown in [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0mss.png).

[scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKJAS.png)

Comment: Have you relaunch the SonarQube analysis ?

Comment: I rescanned the project and the new code with changes appears although the recommendation still apear. If there is another relaunch for analysis than rescanning that would be good to know. I dont see one.

Comment: I am thinking it is because of insufficient memory on the box. It flaps between having code and not having code. Is there a recommended memory requirement?

Comment: Do you see error on Scanner side ? On background tasks side ? Requirements are listed here : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements